# Simple way on how control sprite animation speed

Tags: java, animation, sprite

I'm new to programming and I have some issues on how to control my animation's speed. And I hope that you can give me some tips for this code.

```
public class Maze extends Canvas {  
Map map;
Mario mario;    
private Timer time; 
private BufferStrategy strategy;
private int move;
boolean gameRunning = true; 

public Maze(){
    map = new Map();    
    mario = new Mario();        

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("SuperMario2D");     
    JPanel panel = (JPanel) frame.getContentPane();
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(438, 438));
    panel.setLayout(null);

    setBounds(0, 0, 454, 476);
    panel.add(this);

    setIgnoreRepaint(true);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    addKeyListener(new KeyHandler());
    requestFocus();     

    createBufferStrategy(2);
    strategy = getBufferStrategy();
}   

public void gameLoop() {
    long lastLoopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();     

    while (gameRunning) {
        // work out how long its been since the last update, this
        // will be used to calculate how far the entities should
        // move this loop
        long delta = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastLoopTime;
        lastLoopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) strategy.getDrawGraphics();         
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0,0,800,600);        

        map.draw(g);
        mario.draw(g, move);

        g.dispose();
        strategy.show();
    }

    try { 
        Thread.sleep(10); 
    } catch (Exception e) {}        
}

public class KeyHandler extends KeyAdapter{     
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        int keycode = e.getKeyCode();

        if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            mario.move(0, -1); //if it's not equal this will not execute because Y-1 will equal to w
            move = 1;
            System.out.println("You press up");
        }

        if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            mario.move(0, 1);
            move = 2;
            System.out.println("You press down");
        }

        if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            mario.move(-1, 0);
            move = 3;               
            System.out.println("You press left");
        }

        if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){   
            mario.move(1, 0);
            move = 4;               
            System.out.println("You press right");
        }           
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
        int keycode = e.getKeyCode();

        if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            move = 5;
            System.out.println("You released up");
        }

        if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){                
            move = 6;
            System.out.println("You released down");
        }

        if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){                
            move = 7;
            System.out.println("You released down");
        }

        if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){               
            move = 8;
            System.out.println("You released down");
        }
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){           
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Maze maze = new Maze();

    maze.gameLoop();
}
}
```

here is the code that loads my animated images

```
public class Mario {
private int x, y;
private int tileX, tileY; //for collision   
//private Image player;
private Image[] playerDown = new Image[3];
private Image[] playerUp = new Image[3];
private Image[] playerLeft = new Image[3];
private Image[] playerRight = new Image[3];
private Image[] playerJumpD = new Image[3];
private Image[] playerJumpU = new Image[3];
private Image[] playerJumpL = new Image[3];
private Image[] playerJumpR = new Image[3]; 

private int cycle = 0;
private long scene1 = 0;
private long scene2 = 500;

public Mario(){         
    moveDown();
    moveUp();   
    moveLeft(); 
    moveRight();
    /*
    //jump
    jumpDown();
    jumpUp();
    jumpLeft();
    jumpRight();
    */
    tileX = 1;
    tileY = 1;      
}

public void moveDown(){     
    playerDown[0] = new ImageIcon("images/marioFW1.png").getImage();
    playerDown[1] = new ImageIcon("images/marioFW2.png").getImage();
    playerDown[2] = new ImageIcon("images/marioFW3.png").getImage();
}

public void moveUp(){       
    playerUp[0] = new ImageIcon("images/marioB1.png").getImage();
    playerUp[1] = new ImageIcon("images/marioB2.png").getImage();
    playerUp[2] = new ImageIcon("images/marioB3.png").getImage();
}

public void moveLeft(){     
    playerLeft[0] = new ImageIcon("images/marioJW1.png").getImage();
    playerLeft[1] = new ImageIcon("images/marioJW2.png").getImage();
    playerLeft[2] = new ImageIcon("images/marioJW3.png").getImage();
}

public void moveRight(){        
    playerRight[0] = new ImageIcon("images/marioR1.png").getImage();
    playerRight[1] = new ImageIcon("images/marioR2.png").getImage();
    playerRight[2] = new ImageIcon("images/marioR3.png").getImage();
}
/*
//jump  
public void jumpDown(){

    playerJumpD[0] = new ImageIcon("images/marioFJ1.png").getImage();
    playerJumpD[1] = new ImageIcon("images/marioFJ2.png").getImage();
    playerJumpD[2] = new ImageIcon("images/marioFJ3.png").getImage();
}

public void jumpUp(){       
    playerJumpU[0] = new ImageIcon("images/marioBJ1.png").getImage();
    playerJumpU[1] = new ImageIcon("images/marioBJ2.png").getImage();
    playerJumpU[2] = new ImageIcon("images/marioBJ3.png").getImage();
}

public void jumpLeft(){     
    playerJumpL[0] = new ImageIcon("images/marioJL1.png").getImage();
    playerJumpL[1] = new ImageIcon("images/marioJL2.png").getImage();
    playerJumpL[2] = new ImageIcon("images/marioJL3.png").getImage();
}

public void jumpRight(){        
    playerJumpR[0] = new ImageIcon("images/marioRJ1.png").getImage();
    playerJumpR[1] = new ImageIcon("images/marioRJ2.png").getImage();
    playerJumpR[2] = new ImageIcon("images/marioRJ3.png").getImage();
}
*/
public void move(int dx, int dy){
//  x += dx;
//  y += dy;

    tileX +=  dx;
    tileY += dy;
}

public Image getMoveDown(){     
        if(cycle == playerDown.length){             
            cycle = 0;          
        }   

        return playerDown[cycle++]; 
}   

public Image getMoveUp(){       
    if(cycle == playerUp.length){               
        cycle = 0;          
    }
    return playerUp[cycle++];       
}

public Image getMoveLeft(){     
    if(cycle == playerLeft.length){             
        cycle = 0;          
    }   

    return playerLeft[cycle++]; 
}   

public Image getMoveRight(){        
    if(cycle == playerRight.length){                
        cycle = 0;          
    }   

    return playerRight[cycle++];    
}
/*
//jump
public Image getJumpD(){        
    if(cycle == playerJumpR.length){                
        cycle = 0;          
    }   

    return playerJumpR[cycle++];    
}

public Image getJumpU(){        
    if(cycle == playerJumpU.length){                
        cycle = 0;          
    }   

    return playerJumpU[cycle++];    
}

public Image getJumpL(){        
    if(cycle == playerJumpL.length){                
        cycle = 0;          
    }   

    return playerJumpL[cycle++];    
}

public Image getJumpR(){        
    if(cycle == playerJumpR.length){                
        cycle = 0;          
    }   

    return playerJumpR[cycle++];    
}
*/
/*
public void checkMove(){
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - scene1 < scene2) {
        return;
    }
    scene1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

}
*/
public int getTileX(){
    return tileX;
}

public int getTileY(){
    return tileY;
}

public void draw(Graphics g, int move) {        
    if(move == 0)
        g.drawImage(playerDown[1], getTileX(), getTileY(), null );

    if(move == 1)
        g.drawImage(getMoveUp(), getTileX(), getTileY(), null );

    if(move == 2)
        g.drawImage(getMoveDown(), getTileX(), getTileY(), null );

    if(move == 3)
        g.drawImage(getMoveLeft(), getTileX(), getTileY(), null );

    if(move == 4)
        g.drawImage(getMoveRight(), getTileX(), getTileY(), null );

    if(move == 5)
        g.drawImage(playerUp[1], getTileX(), getTileY(), null );

    if(move == 6)
        g.drawImage(playerDown[1], getTileX(), getTileY(), null );

    if(move == 7)
        g.drawImage(playerLeft[1], getTileX(), getTileY(), null );

    if(move == 8)
        g.drawImage(playerRight[1], getTileX(), getTileY(), null ); 

}

}
```

This is where the map was successfully loaded. I'm not sure how i was able to make i run in accelerated graphics mode.

```
public class Map {  
private Scanner m;
private String[] Map = new String[14]; //how many tiles in the map
private Image tiles, grass2, grass3, grass3b;
private Image wall, sand1;
private Image finish;

public Map(){
    tiles = new ImageIcon("images/grass2.png").getImage();
    wall = new ImageIcon("images/grass1.png").getImage();
    grass2 = new ImageIcon("images/grass2.png").getImage();
    grass3 = new ImageIcon("images/grass3.png").getImage();
    grass3b = new ImageIcon("images/grass3b.png").getImage();
    sand1 = new ImageIcon("images/sand1.png").getImage();
    finish = new ImageIcon("images/tile.png").getImage();       

    openFile();
    readFile();
    closeFile();        
}

public void openFile(){     
    try{
    m = new Scanner(new File("images/Map.txt"));

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Can't open the file: "+e);
    }
}

public void readFile(){
    while(m.hasNext()){ // read through the file
        for(int i = 0; i < 14; i++){
            Map[i] = m.next();              
        }
    }
}

public void closeFile(){
    m.close();
}

public String getMap(int x, int y){
    String index = Map[y].substring(x, x + 1);
    return index;
}

public Image getTiles(){
    return tiles;

}

public Image getWall(){
    return wall;

}

public Image getFinish(){
    return finish;

}   

public Image getImageGrass2(){
    return grass2;
}

public Image getImageGrass3(){
    return grass3;
}

public Image getImageGrass3b(){
    return grass3b;
}

public Image getImageSand1(){
    return sand1;
}
//added
public void draw(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    for(int y = 0; y < 14; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < 14; x++){
            /**draw the finish line**/
            if(getMap(x, y).equals("f")){
                g2.drawImage(getFinish(), x*32,y*32, null);             
            }               
            /**-----------------------)*/
            if(getMap(x, y).equals("g")){
                                        //the size of the image is X 20 by Y20
                g2.drawImage(getTiles(), x*32, y*32, null);
            }

            if(getMap(x, y).equals("w")){
                //the size of the image is X 20 by Y20
                g2.drawImage(getWall(), x*32, y*32, null);
            }

            if(getMap(x, y).equals("d")){
                //the size of the image is X 20 by Y20
                g2.drawImage(getImageGrass3(), x*32, y*32, null);
            }

            if(getMap(x, y).equals("b")){
                //the size of the image is X 20 by Y20
                g2.drawImage(getImageGrass3b(), x*32, y*32, null);
            }

            if(getMap(x, y).equals("s")){
                //the size of the image is X 20 by Y20
                g2.drawImage(getImageSand1(), x*32, y*32, null);
            }

        }           
    }
}       
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. I finally found the answer to my problem. I just need to use a method that synchronizes the images and use System.currentTimeMilli(). and it solve my animation problem. Just watch bucky's video on animation and I was able to apply the concept. :)

Comment: Great! As a friendly reminder, can you please post an answer to the question yourself and then accept that answer so that we can close this question? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.